# Calculating valid host range

Tags: ipv4, subnet, network

what is the first valid host and the last valid host for the network that the IP address 10.150.174.20/17 is a part of?

Comment: A more complete answer is here: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here. Please see the answer Ron linked for how to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP address 10.150.174.20/17 is part of 10.150.128.0/17 network.

First valid host:   10.150.128.1

Last valid host: 10.150.255.254

Broadcast: 10.150.255.255